# hostpython2 build error (for Android using Kivy)

Tags: android, python, kivy, buildozer

I got the following error

```
[INFO]:    # Building recipes
[INFO]:    Building hostpython2 for armeabi-v7a
[INFO]:    -> directory context /home/peter/Documents/testapp/app/.buildozer/android/platform/build/build/other_builds/hostpython2/desktop/hostpython2
[INFO]:    -> directory context /home/peter/Documents/testapp/app/.buildozer/android/platform/build/build/other_builds/hostpython2/desktop/hostpython2/native-build
[INFO]:    <- directory context /home/peter/Documents/testapp/app/.buildozer/android/platform/build/build/other_builds/hostpython2/desktop/hostpython2
[INFO]:    -> running cp Modules/Setup.dist /home/peter/Documents/testapp/app/.buildozer/android/platform/build/build/other_builds/hostpython2/desktop/hostpython2/native-build/Modules/Setup
[INFO]:    -> running make -C /home/peter/Documents/testapp/app/.buildozer/android/platform/build/build/other_builds/hostpython2/desktop/hostpython2/native-build
Exception in thread background thread for pid 23429:                                                                                                                                                       
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/peter/Conda/lib/python3.6/threading.py", line 916, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/home/peter/Conda/lib/python3.6/threading.py", line 864, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/home/peter/Conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sh.py", line 1540, in wrap
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/peter/Conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sh.py", line 2459, in background_thread
    handle_exit_code(exit_code)
  File "/home/peter/Conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sh.py", line 2157, in fn
    return self.command.handle_command_exit_code(exit_code)
  File "/home/peter/Conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sh.py", line 815, in handle_command_exit_code
    raise exc
sh.ErrorReturnCode_2: 

  RAN: /usr/bin/make -C /home/peter/Documents/testapp/app/.buildozer/android/platform/build/build/other_builds/hostpython2/desktop/hostpython2/native-build

  STDOUT:
make: Entering directory '/home/peter/Documents/testapp/app/.buildozer/android/platform/build/build/other_builds/hostpython2/desktop/hostpython2/native-build'
/bin/sh /home/peter/Documents/testapp/app/.buildozer/android/platform/build/build/other_builds/hostpython2/desktop/hostpython2/Modules/makesetup -c /home/peter/Documents/testapp/app/.buildozer/android/platform/build/build/other_builds/hostpython2/desktop/hostpython2/Modules/config.c.in \
            -s Modules \
            Modules/Setup.config \
            Modules/Setup.local \
            Modules/Setup
The Makefile was updated, you may need to re-run make.
gcc -pthread -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes   Parser/acceler.o Parser/grammar1.o Parser/listnode.o Parser/node.o Parser/parser.o Parser/parsetok.o Parser/bitset.o Parser/metagrammar.o Parser/firstsets.o Parser/grammar.o Parser/pgen.o Objects/obmalloc.o Python/mysnprintf.o Python/pyctype.o Parser/tokenizer_pgen.o Parser/printgrammar.o Parser/pgenmain.o -lpthread -ldl  -lutil -o Parser/pgen
gcc: error: Parser/tokenizer_pgen.o: No such file or directory
gcc: error: Parser/printgrammar.o: No such file or directory
gcc: error: Parser/pgenmain.o: No such file or directory
Makefile:566: recipe for target 'Parser/pgen' failed
make: *** [Parser/pgen] Error 1
make: Leaving directory '/home/peter/Documents/testapp/app/.buildozer/android/platform/build/build/other_builds/hostpython2/desktop/hostpython2/native-build'


  STDERR:


Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/peter/Conda/lib/python3.6/runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "/home/peter/Conda/lib/python3.6/runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "/home/peter/Documents/testapp/app/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android-new-toolchain/pythonforandroid/toolchain.py", line 1039, in <module>
    main()
  File "/home/peter/Documents/testapp/app/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android-new-toolchain/pythonforandroid/toolchain.py", line 1033, in main
    ToolchainCL()
  File "/home/peter/Documents/testapp/app/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android-new-toolchain/pythonforandroid/toolchain.py", line 553, in __init__
    getattr(self, args.subparser_name.replace('-', '_'))(args)
  File "/home/peter/Documents/testapp/app/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android-new-toolchain/pythonforandroid/toolchain.py", line 150, in wrapper_func
    build_dist_from_args(ctx, dist, args)
  File "/home/peter/Documents/testapp/app/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android-new-toolchain/pythonforandroid/toolchain.py", line 191, in build_dist_from_args
    build_recipes(build_order, python_modules, ctx)
  File "/home/peter/Documents/testapp/app/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android-new-toolchain/pythonforandroid/build.py", line 634, in build_recipes
    recipe.build_arch(arch)
  File "/home/peter/Documents/testapp/app/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android-new-toolchain/pythonforandroid/python.py", line 382, in build_arch
    result = shprint(sh.make, '-C', build_dir)
  File "/home/peter/Documents/testapp/app/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android-new-toolchain/pythonforandroid/logger.py", line 178, in shprint
    for line in output:
  File "/home/peter/Conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sh.py", line 863, in next
    self.wait()
  File "/home/peter/Conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sh.py", line 792, in wait
    self.handle_command_exit_code(exit_code)
  File "/home/peter/Conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sh.py", line 815, in handle_command_exit_code
    raise exc
sh.ErrorReturnCode_2: 

  RAN: /usr/bin/make -C /home/peter/Documents/testapp/app/.buildozer/android/platform/build/build/other_builds/hostpython2/desktop/hostpython2/native-build

  STDOUT:
make: Entering directory '/home/peter/Documents/testapp/app/.buildozer/android/platform/build/build/other_builds/hostpython2/desktop/hostpython2/native-build'
/bin/sh /home/peter/Documents/testapp/app/.buildozer/android/platform/build/build/other_builds/hostpython2/desktop/hostpython2/Modules/makesetup -c /home/peter/Documents/testapp/app/.buildozer/android/platform/build/build/other_builds/hostpython2/desktop/hostpython2/Modules/config.c.in \
            -s Modules \
            Modules/Setup.config \
            Modules/Setup.local \
            Modules/Setup
The Makefile was updated, you may need to re-run make.
gcc -pthread -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes   Parser/acceler.o Parser/grammar1.o Parser/listnode.o Parser/node.o Parser/parser.o Parser/parsetok.o Parser/bitset.o Parser/metagrammar.o Parser/firstsets.o Parser/grammar.o Parser/pgen.o Objects/obmalloc.o Python/mysnprintf.o Python/pyctype.o Parser/tokenizer_pgen.o Parser/printgrammar.o Parser/pgenmain.o -lpthread -ldl  -lutil -o Parser/pgen
gcc: error: Parser/tokenizer_pgen.o: No such file or directory
gcc: error: Parser/printgrammar.o: No such file or directory
gcc: error: Parser/pgenmain.o: No such file or directory
Makefile:566: recipe for target 'Parser/pgen' failed
make: *** [Parser/pgen] Error 1
make: Leaving directory '/home/peter/Documents/testapp/app/.buildozer/android/platform/build/build/other_builds/hostpython2/desktop/hostpython2/native-build'


  STDERR:

# Command failed: /home/peter/Conda/bin/python -m pythonforandroid.toolchain create --dist_name=kivy_hello_world --bootstrap=sdl2 --requirements=kivy,numpy --ndk-api 9 --arch armeabi-v7a --copy-libs --color=always --storage-dir="/home/peter/Documents/testapp/app/.buildozer/android/platform/build"
# 
# Buildozer failed to execute the last command
# The error might be hidden in the log above this error
# Please read the full log, and search for it before
# raising an issue with buildozer itself.
# In case of a bug report, please add a full log with log_level = 2
```

I googled it and found out that this might be the result of leftovers from old compilation attempts. That is why I used

```
buildozer distclean
```

do get rid of old compiling data. Unfortunately, that changed nothing and the error stays. My only requirements are Kivy and NumPy during the build - both listed in my .spec file. Obviously, the process needs to install respectively build hostpython2 which leads to the error shown above.

Building Kivy should not be the problem but NumPy might be...I used the "official" recipe from the buildozer repo. I tried to install pgen via pip but I did not really know what I was doing - was just a try.

Target platform is Android.

Comment: The `buildozer distclean` cleans the `Buildozer` environment. Not sure if that includes the `.buildozer` directory for your app. Try `buildozer clean` to be sure the `.buildozer` directory is cleaned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Neither `buildozer distclean` nor `buildozer clean` worked so I deleted both the ~/.buildozer and the ./.buildozer directory. That solved the problem.